# Check if object has key, if so, add new key: value to said object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a loop that goes over an array of data `plotData`. Out of `plotData` I build another array called `visiblePoints`. Then I loop over `visiblePoints` to build an object `thisRow`, then I add `thisRow` to an array outside of the loop, called `dataArray`:

```
var dataArray = []

for (i = 0; i < plotData.length; i++) {

    // This filters datapoints array into another array
    var visiblePoints = filterPoints(plotData[i].datapoints)

    // Get the string for the thisRow object key name 
    var selectedParameter = plotData[i].label

    for (k = 0; k < visiblePoints.length; k++) {
        // Convert visiblePoint first value from ms to date
        var timestamp = new Date(visiblePoints[k][0])

        // Form the thisRow object that will go into dataArray
        // for each loop of visiblePoints
        var thisRow = {}
        thisRow["Time"] = msToTime(timestamp)
        thisRow[selectedParameter] = visiblePoints[k][1]
        dataArray.push(thisRow)
    }
}
```

Let's simplify and say I only have 2 element in sub array `visisblePoints` for each `plotData` array, like so (each `plotData` array can have many `visiblePoints` but I'm simplifying to just 2 for each):

```
plotData[0].visiblePoints = [[00:00:01, 1], [00:00:02, 4] ...]
plotData[1].visiblePoints = [[00:00:01, 27], [00:00:02, 31] ...]
```

`plotData` looks like this on the console:

[image]

The `visiblePoints` array for the `k` loop is derived off of `plotData.datapoints` and looks like:

[image]

Where `visiblePoints[n][0]` is a value in ms (that I convert into seconds) and `visiblePoints[n][1]` is just a float value.

```
visiblePoints = 
[0, 0.0500466109191]
[100, 0.0548114598135]
[200, 0.0550143573252]
[300, 0.0549408536766]
[400, 0.0546117305419]
[... repeat 300+ times...]
```

After looping over `plotData[i]` and `visiblePoints[k]` I end up with:

```
dataArray = [
    {
        "Time": 00:00:01,
        "foo": 1
    },
    {
        "Time": 00:00:01,
        "bar": 27
    },
    {
        "Time": 00:00:02,
        "foo": 4
    },
    {
        "Time": 00:00:02,
        "bar": 31
    },
]
```

When I had meant to end up with:

```
dataArray = [
    {
        "Time": 00:00:01,
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 27
    },
    {
        "Time": 00:00:02,
        "foo": 4,
        "bar": 31
    }
]
```

I think in loop `k` I need to go over `dataArray`, check all objects there to see if there is a `Time` key that matches `thisRow["Time"] = msToTime(timestamp)`, and if so, add `thisRow[selectedParameter] = visiblePoints[k][1]` to that, if not, create a new object.

Problems:

1. I'm not sure how to check for this in JS (I'm more experience at Python, and not that much at that
2. It seems like I'm doing a heck of a lot of loops. I'm not sure adding yet another one to go over the entire `dataArray` and check all objects to see if a key exists in one of them is best solution here. A `plotData.visiblePoints` array can be 500+ long.

[EDIT] Simplified the question. Added picture examples. Added text examples of the `k` array.

Comment: No one will appreciate the fact that you provided all the details possible. Make it short and focused.

Comment: how often do you update the array?

Comment: At minimum every 0.5 seconds, this all happens a bit after an event handler is solved

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I tried to make the body explicit to make it clear what my output is and what my desired output should be. Was it **too** explicit?

Comment: @Mormoran I think, yes a bit more than needed. It's just that people don't like to read such long questions. But you seem adequate so I'll try to :)

Comment: @Mormoran i agree Nurbol. you need to be specific.

Comment: @Mormoran -- it would make the question easier to answer if you included a sample of what `plotData` looked like. It seems like it's an array of objects with `label` and `visiblePoints` properties. Is that right?

Comment: Let met get a sample of `plotData`, give me 1 minute

Comment: I simplified the text in the main post and added examples for console outputs for the arrays I'm looping over. Hopefully it's clearer now (and not too explicit/confusing)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or a hash table which keeps the reference to the object with the same time.

```
var map = new Map,
    timestamp,
    row;

// later in loop
timestamp = msToTime(new Date(visiblePoints[k][0]));
row = map.get(timestamp);
if (!row) {
    map.set(timestamp, row = { Time: timestamp });
}
row[selectedParameter] = visiblePoints[k][1];

// at the end assign the array
dataArray = Array.from(map.values())
```

Comment: Where in the loop would I add your map conditional? I think doing it this way would be more efficient but I'm not sure what it is you're doing there (as I mentioned, I'm not very experienced with JS, certainly not this advanced)

Comment: it is the most inner loop with `k` as variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an object keyed to the grouping — in this case the timestamp. This will let you randomly access the item you want without searching the array. When you'r done the `Object.values` of the object will be an array of your grouped objects:

```js
let plotData = [
    {
        label: 'foo',
        visiblePoints: [[`00:00:01`, 1], [`00:00:02`, 4]]
    },
    {
        label: 'bar',
        visiblePoints: [[`00:00:01`, 27], [`00:00:02`, 31]]
    }
]

let groups = plotData.reduce((obj, {label, visiblePoints}) => {
    visiblePoints.forEach(([time, val]) => {
        if(!obj[time]) obj[time] = {Time: time}  // if we haven't seen this time make a new object at that key
        obj[time][label] = val
    })
    return obj
},   {})
console.log(Object.values(groups))
```

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your snippet to my code, give me a second. Your seems the most efficient, as I don't want to loop over this too much. Also added more examples. But running your snippet here seems to do exactly what I meant to do at first.

Answer (score 0):

You could find if an `Object` has a specific key by calling `hasOwnProperty` method.

```js
const obj = {
  "bar": [1,2,3],
  "foo": "im foo"
};

console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("bar"))
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("bar2"))
```

And you need to follow this pattern.

```js
var dataArray = []

for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    
        thisRow = {};
        thisRow["Time"] = k+1 * i+1
        thisRow["foo"] = i+1
        thisRow["var"] = k+1
        dataArray.push(thisRow)
    }
}

console.log(dataArray)
```